# Rails how to query a hash in a where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, rails-activerecord

Is there a way with active record sql server adapter to query a hash field? I have a field called properties that is stored like this:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
summary: There is a problem
optional_information: Help!!
location: '28288'
reported_phone: "(555) 555-0352"
reported_email: person@email.com
affected_person_id: '1234'
affected_person_name: 'Tester'
affected_person_phone: '(555) 555-0352'
affected_person_email: person@email.com
```

I want to set up a query so that I pass a param through called filter and query either the summary field of the hash. Is this possible?

Trying to do somethings like this:

```
@requests = current_user.requests.where("properties->>'summary' = ?", '%#{params[:filter]}%') if params[:filter].present?
```

UPDATE: Per the advice below I changed the model to serialize the field as JSON. I also ran a migration to change the DB field type to JSON. Here is what the field looks like now. Still trying to figure out how to access and query the individual values.

```
{"summary":"Need bed raised","optional_information":"too low","location":"26679","reported_phone":"(555) 334-1324","reported_email":"mail@mail.com","affected_person_id":"1231232","affected_person_name":"testuserJ ","affected_person_phone":"(555) 334-1324","affected_person_email":"mail@mail.com"}
```

Comment: I just updated my post with an example of what I am trying to do. How do you reference has fields in a where clause?

Comment: "has fields" meaning...part of a JSON document in the database?

Comment: You are trying to use JSON query methods to access what appears to be YAML. Recommendation would be to store it as JSON then you can query it.

Comment: Looks like you're doing `serialize :properties` so you have a blob of YAML in a text column in the database. Can you change the database schema to use something easier to work with?

Comment: What do you suggest changing it to? SQL server does not have a json type as far as I know.

Comment: @spacerobot You should at least serialize it as JSON. MSSQL server does have [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) for working with JSON. You can change the serializer as `serialize :properties, JSON` but before doing that you will likely have to run a migration to update the data in the database.

Comment: Thanks! What would the migration be doing? Changing the column from text to what?

Comment: Updated the db and changed the serialize to json. How to you reference the individual values though?

Comment: @spacerobot does it work? I assumed there would be some issues trying to deserialize that YAML as JSON.

Comment: I only had a couple of records in the table so I deleted them and started over. I set the field in the model to serialize json and did a migration to change the field type to json.

Comment: I updated my post with the new DB value.

Comment: What is preventing you from using a table instead? Is the data really so unstructured that you need to store JSON/YAML in a text column?

Comment: I'm starting to think that. I did it this way because the fields are dynamic and change between service requests. For instance a service request of event scheduling requires location, details and start date/time end date/time while an SR with a classification of billable service requires a chart string field. So Srs have one classification. Classifications have many class fields. I was having trouble plotting all that out with tables so I went this route. I think I need to plan to get it back to tables though given the issues.

Comment: I think you'll have to do some reading on SQL Server's JSON functions to figure out how to query things now that you have JSON.